# Get a sequence with difference using for loop in PHP

Tags: php, for-loop

How to get a sequence like (50 difference)

```
100,150,200,250,.....,900.
```

using 2 values (100 & 900).

My try gets an increment with 50,

```
for($i=100;$i<900;$i++)
{
    $ii=$i+50;
    echo '<option value="'.$ii.'">'.$ii.'</option>';
}
```

Comment: 3rd part of a for loop is the increment part. And right now you have `$i++` there.

Comment: `for ($i = 100; $i <= 900; $i += 50)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go simple like this:

```
for($i=100;$i<=900;$i+=50)
{
    echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
}
```

Also if you wanted to include 900, use `<=` not just `<`

Your [Eval](https://eval.in/569498)

Answer (score 0):

Another option: use `range()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)

```
$sequence = range(100, 900, 50);
foreach ($sequence as $step) { 
    echo '<option value="' . $step . '">' . $step . '</option>';
}
```

This is less memory efficient than a for loop, but I believe it is more readable. In PHP 5.5 you can make it both efficient and readable by defining a generator version of `range` (a-la the Python `xrange`). See the first example here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php